# Select all the text on tap of the ion-input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, ionic4

How to select all the text in ion-input.

below are the method which i tried to select all the text in the textbox.

trail1:

```
<ion-input (tap)="selectAll($event)" type="text" />

selectAll(event){
  event.target.select();
  //window.document.element.select()
}
```

Trail2:

```
<ion-input (tap)="this.select()" type="text" />
```

Trail3:

```
<ion-input (tap)="this.setSelectionRange(0,value.length)" type="text" />
```

Trail4:

```
  <ion-input #textbox (tap)="selectAll()" type="text" />

@ViewChild('textbox ') textbox ;
this.textbox .nativeElement.select();
```

Nothing is working for me.

if any other trial please let me know

Comment: Why can't you try focus instead of tap?

Answer (score 2):

I changed your first trial a little and that seems to work. Ion-Input is a wrapper around a html input element. To select all the text inside, you need to differentiate two cases: Either you clicked/tapped on the inner html input directly, then you can use `select()` directly on the target, or you clicked/tapped on outer ion-input wrapper, then you need to access the child input first. Something like this.

```
 <ion-input (tap)="select($event)"></ion-input>

 select(event: any) {
   if (event.target.select) { // tapped directly on html input
     event.target.select();
   } else if (event.target.children[0].select) { // tapped on the wrapper
     event.target.children[0].select();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a directive for this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-searchbar[select-all],ion-input[select-all]'
})
export class SelectAllDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }      

  @HostListener('click')
  selectAll() {
    // access to the native input element
    let nativeEl: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    if (nativeEl) {
      if (nativeEl.setSelectionRange) {
        // select the text from start to end
        return nativeEl.setSelectionRange(0, nativeEl.value.length);
      }
      nativeEl.select();
    }
  }

}
```

I created a module for this directive:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectAllDirective } from './select-all.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SelectAllDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    SelectAllDirective
  ]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }
```

I imported this module in myPage and the AppModule and then, and used the directive in the html:

```
<ion-input select-all>...
```

Source Base: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-input-select-all-text-on-focus/79406/3